# How can I make sure a reference entry is always followed by its erratum?

Tags: biblatex

I am making references with package `biblatex` and I would like the a reference entry is always followed by its erratum, if there is any, so that people do not miss it.

The issue is, I also want the reference items numbered by order of their appearance in the text. Under this condition, if the erratum was not cited immediately after its main entry, it will not follow it.

Can I make sure a reference entry is always followed by its erratum regardless of the numbering rules?

Here is an example of what I am doing right now

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks = false, pdfborderstyle ={/S/D}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none, maxnames = 3, minnames = 2, backref = true, backrefstyle = three, arxiv = abs, doi = true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{biber.bib}
@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross section in $p p$ collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 2.76 \mathrm{TeV}$ and comparison to the inclusive jet cross section at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using the ATLAS detector},
journal = {The European Physical Journal C},
year = {2013},
month = {August},
volume = {73},
number = {2509},
doi = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-013-2509-4},
}

@article
{
a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
month = {February},
title = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
volume = {02},
number = {153},
year = {2015},
doi = {10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153},
addendum = {\textbf{Erratum}: \cite{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}},
}

@article
{
a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
author = {G. Aad and others},
title = {Erratum: Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt{s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
year = {2015},
month = {September},
volume = {09},
number = {141},
doi = {10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{biber.bib}

\begin{document}

I will first cite \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}, which has the erratum, then \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet}.

\newpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and here is the reference page it produced

[image: erratum]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you could use entry sets to your advantage. Both the paper and its erratum could then be listed using the same number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other `sorting` settings it would be possible to tweak the sorting of the erratum with `sortyear` and `sorttitle` so that it always appears after the relevant article. But with `sorting=none,` no property of the `.bib` entry controls the sort position: All that matters is the order in which the entries are cited in the TeX document. So you would have to manually `\nocite` the erratum directly after you cite the article for the first time. Of course that is tedious and prone to errors.

## Entry sets

As mentioned by [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529741/how-can-i-make-sure-a-reference-entry-is-always-followed-by-its-erratum#comment1339802_529741) you could use a `@set`-based approach to combine both entries into one. With the `subentry` option it is still possible to refer to each item individually. That could be turned off, but then you would probably want to get rid of the `addendum = {\textbf{Erratum}: \cite{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}},` as the output then looks a bit circular.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none,
  subentry,
  maxnames = 3, minnames = 2,
  backref = true, backrefstyle = three,
  arxiv = abs, doi = true]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet,
  author  = {G. Aad and others},
  title   = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross section in
             $p p$ collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 2.76 \mathrm{TeV}$
             and comparison to the inclusive jet cross section
             at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using the ATLAS detector},
  journal = {The European Physical Journal C},
  year    = {2013},
  month   = aug,
  volume  = {73},
  number  = {2509},
  doi     = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-013-2509-4},
}
@article{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
  author   = {G. Aad and others},
  journal  = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  month    = feb,
  title    = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section
              in proton-proton collisions
              at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$
              using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$
              of data with the ATLAS detector},
  volume   = {02},
  number   = {153},
  year     = {2015},
  doi      = {10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153},
  addendum = {\textbf{Erratum}: \cite{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}},
}
@article{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
  author  = {G. Aad and others},
  title   = {Erratum: Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section
             in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt{s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$
             using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
  journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  year    = {2015},
  month   = sep,
  volume  = {09},
  number  = {141},
  doi     = {10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141},
}
@set{atlasset,
  entryset= {a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I will first cite \cite{atlasset}, which has the erratum,
then \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] (a) G. Aad et al. In: Journal of High Energy Physics 02.153 (Feb. 2015). doi: 10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153. Erratum: [1b]; (b) G. Aad et al. In: Journal of High Energy Physics 09.141 (Sept. 2015). doi: 10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141. Cit. on p. 1.]

You don't have to define a `@set` entry in the `.bib` file. If you like you can define a set dynamically from the `.tex` file. See §3.13.5 *Entry Sets* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

## `related` entries

`@set`s are nice, but their behaviour is not particularly well defined in non-`numeric` styles. They are also usually intended to group entries of the same kind and not to group entries with a sport of parent-child relation.

A parent-child relation is usually modelled using `biblatex`'s `related` feature. The advantage of the `related` feature is that it can make the relation between the entries explicit in the data and that the child entry can be processed in a way such that the data of the parent is still available, which makes it possible to integrate the two entries more closely.

There is no pre-defined `related` feature for errata, but the default definitions with a few modifications already give a reasonable result. (Note that the `author` field is automatically suppressed because it is the same as that of the parent entry. If the names were different, they would be shown. Of course that can be tweaked.)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style = numeric, sorting = none,
  subentry,
  maxnames = 3, minnames = 2,
  backref = true, backrefstyle = three,
  arxiv = abs, doi = true]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
    }
  }
}

\NewBibliographyString{erratum}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  erratum = {erratum},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{relatedstring:erratum}{\mkbibbold{#1}\printunit{\relatedpunct}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet,
  author  = {G. Aad and others},
  title   = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross section in
             $p p$ collisions at $\sqrt({s} = 2.76 \mathrm{TeV}$
             and comparison to the inclusive jet cross section
             at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$ using the ATLAS detector},
  journal = {The European Physical Journal C},
  year    = {2013},
  month   = aug,
  volume  = {73},
  number  = {2509},
  doi     = {10.1140/epjc/s10052-013-2509-4},
}
@article{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
  author   = {G. Aad and others},
  journal  = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  month    = feb,
  title    = {Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section
              in proton-proton collisions
              at $\sqrt({s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$
              using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$
              of data with the ATLAS detector},
  volume   = {02},
  number   = {153},
  year     = {2015},
  doi      = {10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153},
  related  = {a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet},
  relatedtype = {erratum},
}
@article{a.aad.erratum_atlas_2011_7_tev_jet,
  author  = {G. Aad and others},
  title   = {Erratum: Measurement of the inclusive jet cross-section
             in proton-proton collisions at $\sqrt{s} = 7 \mathrm{TeV}$
             using $4.5 \mathrm{fb}^{−1}$ of data with the ATLAS detector},
  journal = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  year    = {2015},
  month   = sep,
  volume  = {09},
  number  = {141},
  doi     = {10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I will first cite \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_7_tev_jet}, which has the erratum,
then \cite{a.aad.atlas_2011_2.76_tev_jet}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: G. Aad et al. In: Journal of High Energy Physics 02.153 (Feb. 2015). doi: 10.1007/JHEP02(2015)153 (cit. on p. 1). Erratum in: Journal of High Energy Physics 09.141 (Sept. 2015). doi: 10.1007/JHEP09(2015)141.]